# How to add extra context data in LISTVIEW without breaking built-in pagination

Tags: django, django-views, django-pagination

Question about pagination issue:

Why if I have for example following LISTVIEW:

```py
class BoatListView(ListView):
    model = BoatModel
    template_name = "boats.html"
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = ListView.get_context_data(self, object_list=None, **kwargs)
        context["boats"] = BoatModel.objects.all()
        context["images"] = BoatImage.objects.all()
        return context
```

and I would use “boats” and “images” context in template , for example :

```py
{% for boat in boats %}
some code here
{% endfor %}
...
…
….
{% bootstrap_pagination page_obj    %}
```

paginator will not work at all in this case ( bootstrap one  or original Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view), no difference?

But as soon as I change  “boats” and “images” to “object_list” - paginator would begin pagination.

Whats the problem and how in this case could I add extra context in view if I need to do so within ability to use paiginator indeed?

Thank you!

Comment: i suggest you to use end-less pagination https://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: How does django know which model to use for pagination ( I am refering to the django pagination)?

Comment: But *why* would you think this would work at all? Django isn't magic, how is it supposed to know that your `boats` queryset is supposed to be paginated? There is no reason to do what you're doing, stop doing it.

Comment: @ger.s.brett  Probably from here: model = BoatModel

Comment: @Daniel Roseman . I get it. Qestion really is how to use something outside 'object_list' in this scenario...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` declares an attribute `object_list` which takes the queryset from `get_queryset()`. When constructing the `context`, this attribute is used to define pagination. You can override the behaviour of the pagination in `get_context_data` itself by changing what is sent as a queryset in `self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)`(I don't see a reason to do this though).

Take a look at how ListView works [here](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.list/ListView/).